# How to make setting scrollTop scroll to the point instantly?

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrolltop

I'm trying to scroll to a certain block on page load like this (needs to work in IE 11):

```
getScrollbaleContainer().scrollTop = 
         block.getBoundingClientRect().top + 
         (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop);
```

But Chromium browsers and Firefox scroll to that point with a duration. Is there a way to make it scroll instantly?

Comment: create a working snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting and unsetting the [scroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) css property:

```
const container = getPageScrollContainer();
container.style.scrollBehavior = 'auto';
container.scrollTop = 
              block.getBoundingClientRect().top + 
              (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop);
container.style.scrollBehavior = '';
```